# How do you display information from a database in python?

Tags: python, database, pyqt4

I am new to Python and I am trying to make a flashcard script that retrieves the keyword and the definition from a database and then displays both on a flashcard using pyqt.

Does anyone know how to do this because I am having real trouble figuring it out.

So far, I have some pseudo code below.

```
Function loadFlashcards(topic)

Import sqlite3

With sqlite3.connect (‘db_flashcards’) as db:
  Cursor = db.cursor()
  Sql = ‘SELECT * FROM tbl_flashcards’;
  Cursor.execute(sql)
  Result = cursor.fetchall()
  for row in result:
    print(“Defintion:” + str(row[2]
    flip = input(“Press 1 to flip”)
    if flip ==   “1”:
        then print (“Keyword: +str[3])
    else:
        print(“Error”)
END for
```

Comment: Apart from the strangely capitalised keywords and the lack of indentation after `with`, what's wrong with this code?

Comment: We need you to show what you have tried, the pseudocode does not help at all because it is only a schematic idea, but it is not a code that can be reproduced and therefore it is impossible to give you an adequate diagnosis. you must provide a [mcve]